# How can I select a beginning...ending portion of a '/' delimited string (PS1 prompt in my case)

Tags: bash, prompt, string

I am customizing my PS1 prompt, specifically the $PWD part which is delimited by `/`'s

among several things I like having the current directory.
However if the directory is too long I'd like to have beginning...ending

For example, instead of

```
otherstuff:~/apps/webs/2014/area1/groupa/current:other_stuff $
```

I'd like to have the first directories and the last two, i.e.

```
otherstuff:~/apps/webs/.../groups/current:other_stuff $
```

It should handle when they partially overlap, i.e.

```
   otherstuff:~/apps/webs/2014:other_stuff $ 
-> otherstuff:~/apps/webs/2014:other_stuff $
```

and when they are the same, i.e.

```
   otherstuff:~/apps/webs/:other_stuff $ 
-> otherstuff:~/apps/webs/:other_stuff $
```

I tried various substrings if $PWD using {}, () and {} but can't get the format right.

Update - I used the information in guidos answer (accepted) to put together this:

```
parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}
PS1='\033[01;31m\]\t\033[00m\]:'
PS1=$PS1'\[\033[01;32m\]\u\033[00m\]:\033[01;34m\]'
PS1=$PS1'`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+/\).*\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+\)/\?#\1...\2#g"`'
PS1=$PS1'\033[00m\]:\033[01;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```

which yields:

[image]

A sad amount of the code is repeated `\033[00m\]:`'s for the 3 white colon seperator !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sed command runs a regex that should be helpful for your task:

```
 sed 's#\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+/\).*\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+\)/\?#\1...\2#g'
```

Test:

```
PS1PWD_REGEX='s#\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+/\).*\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+\)/\?#\1...\2#g'
$ echo "~/apps/webs/2014/" | sed $PS1PWD_REGEX 
~/apps/webs/2014/
$ echo "~/apps/webs/chip/mips/2014/" | sed $PS1PWD_REGEX 
~/apps/webs/.../mips/2014
$ echo "~/apps/webs/chip/mips/2014" | sed $PS1PWD_REGEX 
~/apps/webs/.../mips/2014
$ echo "/apps/webs/chip/mips/clips/2014" | sed $PS1PWD_REGEX 
/apps/webs/.../clips/2014
$ echo "/" | sed $PS1PWD_REGEX 
/
$ echo "~" | sed $PS1PWD_REGEX
~
```

You might then setup your profile in the lines:

```
export PS1='[\u@\h `pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+/\).*\(/[^/]\+/[^/]\+\)/\?#\1...\2#g"`]\$ '
```

I myself prefer a multiline prompt which gives plenty of space for long paths on the first line.

Comment: +1  yeah I go with the carriage return at the end but I am displaying so much other stuff in my PS1 now that even the full dir path is too long!  Thanks for this great answer.  likely to accept it. upvoted as a minimum.

Comment: you welcome; did you try something from here? some awesome stuff (maybe even _too_ much for my eyes): http://www.askapache.com/linux/bash-power-prompt.html

Comment: yup, see my updated answer!  Includes git branch!

Answer (score 1):

You should just split it and choose the parts you want:

```
( IFS=/ ; set -- $string 
  while ${1+:} false ; do 
    echo "$1" ; shift
  done
)
```

To get only the beginning/end:

```
start_end="$(IFS=/ ; set -- $string ; unset IFS
    printf '/%s/.../%s' "$1" \
        "`shift $(($#-1)) ; echo "$1"`"
)"
```